# import of project from bitbucket is incorrect on eclipse oxygen (use src.main as part of the package name)

Tags: eclipse, maven, bitbucket, pom.xml, jhipster

I'm trying to checkout a JHipster project from bitbucket and while able to do so on my office computer (A), I'm unable to get the same result on my home-computer (B).

Both IDE I'm using are eclipse-oxygen and I'm on the Java Perspective. You will note from picture B that the import (which done the same way on A) consider the src.main.java as part of the package so the compiler indicates an error that the package name is incorrect.

while A has `src/main/java`

B has `src.main.java.com...`

How can I fix B?

[image]

[image]

snapshot of pom.xml (stack overflow limits to 30K chars)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.boyern.pqp</groupId>
    <artifactId>pqp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Pqp</name>

    <properties>
        <argLine>-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Xmx256m</argLine>
        <assertj.version>3.6.2</assertj.version>
        <awaitility.version>2.0.0</awaitility.version>
        <commons-io.version>2.5</commons-io.version>
        <commons-lang.version>3.5</commons-lang.version>
        <cucumber.version>1.2.4</cucumber.version>
        <dockerfile-maven-plugin.version>1.3.4</dockerfile-maven-plugin.version>
        <!-- Overridden to get metrics-jcache -->
        <dropwizard-metrics.version>3.2.2</dropwizard-metrics.version>
        <frontend-maven-plugin.version>1.4</frontend-maven-plugin.version>
        <gatling.version>2.2.5</gatling.version>
        <gatling-maven-plugin.version>2.2.4</gatling-maven-plugin.version>
        <hazelcast-hibernate52.version>1.2</hazelcast-hibernate52.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.2.10.Final</hibernate.version>
        <hikaricp.version>2.6.0</hikaricp.version>
        <jacoco-maven-plugin.version>0.7.9</jacoco-maven-plugin.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <jcache.version>1.0.0</jcache.version>
        <jzlib.version>1.1.3</jzlib.version>
        <jhipster.server.version>1.1.9</jhipster.server.version>
        <jjwt.version>0.7.0</jjwt.version>
        <liquibase-hibernate5.version>3.6</liquibase-hibernate5.version>
        <liquibase-slf4j.version>2.0.0</liquibase-slf4j.version>
        <logstash-logback-encoder.version>4.11</logstash-logback-encoder.version>
        <m2e.apt.activation>jdt_apt</m2e.apt.activation>
        <mapstruct.version>1.1.0.Final</mapstruct.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.6.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven-enforcer-plugin.version>1.4.1</maven-enforcer-plugin.version>
        <maven-resources-plugin.version>3.0.1</maven-resources-plugin.version>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMddHHmmss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.version>3.0.0</maven.version>
        <metrics-spring.version>3.1.3</metrics-spring.version>
        <node.version>v6.11.1</node.version>
        <problem-spring-web.version>0.20.0</problem-spring-web.version>
        <!-- These remain empty unless the corresponding profile is active -->
        <profile.no-liquibase />
        <profile.swagger />
        <prometheus-simpleclient.version>0.0.20</prometheus-simpleclient.version>
        <!-- Sonar properties -->
        <project.testresult.directory>${project.build.directory}/test-results</project.testresult.directory>
        <run.addResources>false</run.addResources>
        <scala-maven-plugin.version>3.2.2</scala-maven-plugin.version>
        <scala.version>2.12.1</scala.version>
        <sonar-maven-plugin.version>3.2</sonar-maven-plugin.version>

        <sonar.exclusions>src/main/webapp/content/**/*.*, src/main/webapp/bower_components/**/*.*, src/main/webapp/i18n/*.js, target/www/**/*.*</sonar.exclusions>

        <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria>S3437,UndocumentedApi,BoldAndItalicTagsCheck</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria>

        <!-- Rule https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#rule_key=Web%3ABoldAndItalicTagsCheck is ignored. Even if we agree that using the "i" tag is an awful practice, this is what is recommended by http://fontawesome.io/examples/ -->
        <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.BoldAndItalicTagsCheck.resourceKey>src/main/webapp/app/**/*.*</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.BoldAndItalicTagsCheck.resourceKey>
        <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.BoldAndItalicTagsCheck.ruleKey>Web:BoldAndItalicTagsCheck</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.BoldAndItalicTagsCheck.ruleKey>
        <!-- Rule https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AS3437 is ignored, as a JPA-managed field cannot be transient -->
        <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.S3437.resourceKey>src/main/java/**/*</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.S3437.resourceKey>
        <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.S3437.ruleKey>squid:S3437</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.S3437.ruleKey>
        <!-- Rule http://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AUndocumentedApi is ignored, as we want to follow "clean code" guidelines and classes, methods and arguments names should be self-explanatory -->
        <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.UndocumentedApi.resourceKey>src/main/java/**/*</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.UndocumentedApi.resourceKey>
        <sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.UndocumentedApi.ruleKey>squid:UndocumentedApi</sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.UndocumentedApi.ruleKey>

        <sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>${project.testresult.directory}/coverage/jacoco/jacoco-it.exec</sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>
        <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.testresult.directory}/coverage/jacoco/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
        <sonar.java.codeCoveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.codeCoveragePlugin>

        <sonar.javascript.jstestdriver.reportsPath>${project.testresult.directory}/karma</sonar.javascript.jstestdriver.reportsPath>
        <!-- For Sonar < 6.2 -->
        <sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath>${project.testresult.directory}/coverage/report-lcov/lcov.info</sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath>
        <!-- For Sonar >= 6.2 -->
        <sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths>${project.testresult.directory}/coverage/report-lcov/lcov.info</sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths>

        <sonar.sources>${project.basedir}/src/main/</sonar.sources>
        <sonar.surefire.reportsPath>${project.testresult.directory}/surefire-reports</sonar.surefire.reportsPath>
        <sonar.tests>${project.basedir}/src/test/</sonar.tests>

        <!-- Spring properties -->
        <springfox.version>2.7.0</springfox.version>
        <validation-api.version>1.1.0.Final</validation-api.version>
        <yarn.version>v0.27.5</yarn.version>
    </properties>
```

problem on pom.xml
[image]

Comment: Could you please add the content of the `pom.xml` file of project B to your question?

Comment: @howlger  just did. Mind that stockoverflow limits the post to 30K. Thanks for helping.

Comment: If _Project > Clean..._ does not fix the problem, check if there is a _Maven Project Builder_ in _Project > Properties: Builders_.

Comment: Rrr non works. Yes, there's Maven Project Builder under Builders. I'll add a snapshot of the problem on the pom.xml

Comment: In the `pom.xml`file, if you temporarily comment out the parts where an error is displayed, are the source folders correctly configured?

Comment: nope. didn't do that trick. I just deleted the ~.m2/repository folder (see if the initialization will workout)

Comment: In this case you have to configure the source folders manually. Specify the same source folders than in a new Maven project: _Project > Properties: Java Build Path: Source_.

Comment: @howlger thanks. You were right. The problem was with the pom.xml. I deleted the m2/repositories and it did the trick (it took some time). Why don't you post your answer and I'll give you the credit you deserve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **source folder(s)** of the project **are not correct configured**: the project folder instead of `src/main/java`, `src/main/resources` is set as source folder by mistake.

For Maven projects the Maven project builder should set the source folder(s) based on the content of the `pom.xml` file. Therefore, **check the `pom.xml` file for errors**. In your case, the error message in the `pom.xml` file could indicate an invalid local Maven repository. Deleting the repository might solve your problem.